# Неожиданная ошибка при автосохранение вложений по условию в Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку. Пытаюсь настроить автосохранение вложений в `outlook 2016`, скрипт работает, но иногда выполняется с неизвестными ошибками, не знаю с чем это может быть связано.

Например, получаю письмо, срабатывает правило по названию темы письма, в котором есть вложения, срабатывает скрипт VBA -> скачиваю 5-6 файлов `docx`, `pdf`, `excel` — всё нормально. Но стоит получить письмо формата ED или ещё что, получаю ошибку:

> Произошла неожиданная ошибка

[Снимок ошибки](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/TZpc1MEGFm4CsQ).

Скрипт на VBA:

```
Public Sub saveAtt (itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment 'переменная для работы с вложениями
Dim saveFolder As String 'переменная для пути к папке сохранения
Dim sDateMail as string 'переманная для даты письма
'сохраняем в правильном формате время создания сообщения
sDateMail = Format(itm.CreationTime, "hh-mm-ss_dd.mm.yyyy")

'задаем путь к папке сохранения
saveFolder = "C:\TEST\"
'перебираем все вложения в письме
For each objAtt in itm.Attachments
'сохраняем вложение в папку под именем: дата письма + название файла вложения
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & sDateMail & "_" & objAtt.FileName
'очищаем переменную с вложением
Set objAtt = Nothing
Next objAtt

End Sub
```

Comment: Аналогичная ошибка, перерыл всю сеть, ответа не нашел. Возникает при сохранение XLSX файлов. Мне кажется она возникает не в зависимости от формата файла, а по какой-то иной причине. Причем 2-3 раза на одном и том-же файле отрабатывает нормально, а на следующий раз запинается.

Comment: @Lenin согласен с тобой, тоже такое замечал, у меня так ещё из-за подписи ломался. (картинка png)